# MySQL duplicates data in SELECT from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, many-to-many

I have 6 tables, according to following structure
[image: erd]
the query i am using

```
SELECT 
    campaigns.idCampaign,

    users.idUser AS idUser,
    users.identification AS userIdentification,
    users.name AS userName,
    campaign_users.commission AS userCommission,
    campaign_files.idFile AS idFile,
    campaign_files.name AS fileName,
    clients.identification AS clientIdentification,
    suppliers.identification AS supplierIdentification
FROM
    campaigns
    LEFT JOIN campaign_users ON( campaigns.idCampaign = campaign_users.idCampaign)
    LEFT JOIN users ON( users.idUser = campaign_users.idUser )
    LEFT JOIN clients USING( idClient )
    LEFT JOIN suppliers ON ( suppliers.idSupplier = campaigns.idSupplier )
    LEFT JOIN campaign_files ON( campaigns.idCampaign = campaign_files.idCampaign)
```

This results in duplicate campaigns, according to the number of files in `campaign_files` or users in `campaign_users` (which is greater).

[image: the result of the query]
this is the result, as you can see the `idCampaign` is same but multiple times, i want to this in single object, like this

```
{

    idCampaign: 4,
    users: [
        {
            idUser: 1,
            userName: 'ADMIN' 
        },
        {
            idUser: 2,
            userName: 'Serena Huel'
        }
    ],
    files: [
        {
            idFile: 23,
            fileName: 'dshds9agds86das8gads8g5dsa.hal'
        },
        {
            idFile: 49,
            fileName: 'dshds9agds86das8gads8g5dsa.hal'
        }
        {
            idFile: 84,
            fileName: 'dshds9agds86das8gads8g5dsa.hal'
        },
        {
            idFile: 99,
            fileName: 'dshds9agds86das8gads8g5dsa.hal'
        }
    ],
    clientIdentification: "dolore",
    ...
}
```

I have added the output as example but it can be PHP object, array etc.

Comment: What do you expect?  Your query is asking for all the files, so of course there will be duplicates.  Perhaps you should edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have added the sample returned data, will this help understand the problem?

Comment: Your results do not have dplicates.  The `idFile` and `fileName` columns differ on each row.

Comment: I understand, but the `idCampaign` is same and i want this to be a single object

Comment: `GROUP BY idUser` will remove the files

Comment: @SalalAslam So what exactly is the expected output? One row with which fields? (please edit in question)

Comment: do you want unique file name with data ? because every thing is same except `fileid` and `filename`

Comment: please check the edit, i have added `json` output as an example but it can be PHP object, array etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not how MySQL works. You could do a `GROUP BY` and something like `GROUP_CONCAT`, but this would leave you with strings and not arrays. So why not turn it into the wanted object in PHP?

Assuming the query can return multiple `campaignId`s, you could do it like this

```
$campaigns = array();

while ($row = /* fetch row */) {
    if (!isSet($campaigns[ $row['campaignId'] ])) {
        //new campaignId
        $campaigns[ $row['campaignId'] ] = array(
            'users' => array(),
            'files' => array(),
            'clientIdentification' => $row['clientIdentification']
        );
    }

    if (!isSet($campaigns[ $row['campaignId'] ]['users'][ $row['idUser'] ])) {
        //new user
        $campaigns[ $row['campaignId'] ]['users'][ $row['idUser'] ] = $row['userName'];
    }

    $campaigns[ $row['campaignId'] ]['files'][] = array(
        'idFile' => $row['idFile'],
        'fileName' => $row['fileName']
    );
}
```

This will give you an array `$campaigns` which is nearly what you want. Saving the users using the id as key is a simple method to not have any duplicate users. Now to get the expected object, you can do something like

```
foreach ($campaigns as $c) {
    $expectedObj = array(
        'idCampaign' => $c['idCampaign'],
        'users' => array(),
        'files' => $c['files'],
        'clientIdentification' => $c['clientIdentification']
    );
    foreach ($c['users'] as $idUser => $userName) {
        $expectedObj['users'][] = array(
            'idUser' => $idUser,
            'userName' => $userName
        );
    }
    // use $expectedObj
}
```